# Macro to import CSV file into Excel 2010 without losing leading zeroes or cell formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros, csv

We have a UI based application that exports data out of a form into a CSV file.  The data entered may have leading zeroes in some numeric fields and/or text with line feeds in other fields.

Currently, if we open the CSV in Excel, Excel strips the leading zeroes from the numeric fields, but it keeps the line feeds in the text fields.

If we import the CSV into Excel as text, we get the leading zeroes, but the text with the line feeds appears on multiple rows instead of in a single field.

Is there a macro that we can right that will allow us to import the CSV into Excel and keep both the leading zeroes in the numeric fields and the line feeds in the text fields?

Answer (score 0):

Double-quote the fields containing line breaks to retain the formatting.

Excel won't strip the leading zeroes if you save the numbers in the CSV like this: `="00100"`.